# Understanding the derivation of Killing horizon surface gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vector-fields

In the book "A Relativist's Toolkit" by Eric Poisson, he explains surface gravity in section 5.2.4

The equation 5.40 says

$$ (-t^\mu  t_\mu)_{;\alpha} = 2 \kappa t_\alpha \tag{5.40}$$

where $t^\alpha$ is a killing vector.

And then equation 5.41 says

t$^\alpha$ $_{; \beta}$ t$^\beta$ = $\kappa$ t$^\alpha$

How to get equation 5.41 from 5.40 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $t^{\alpha}$ is a killing vector, we have
\begin{equation}
t_{\alpha;\mu}+t_{\mu;\alpha}=0.
\end{equation}
Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(-t_{\mu}t^{\mu})_{;\alpha} &= -2t_{\mu;\alpha}t^{\mu} \\
&= 2 t_{\alpha;\mu}t^{\mu}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: t$^\mu$ $_{; \alpha}$ t$_\mu$ = t$_\mu$ $_{; \alpha}$ t$^\mu$ ?

Comment: why it is like that ?

Comment: @apk Since ${g^{\mu\nu}}_{;\alpha}=0$, we have ${t^{\mu}}_{;\alpha} t_{\mu}=(g^{\mu\nu}t_{\nu})_{;\alpha} t_{\mu}=t_{\nu;\alpha} g^{\mu\nu}t_{\mu} = t_{\nu;\alpha}t^{\nu}$.